# How to add custom field to mongoengine model?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a Project model as follows:

```
class Project(me.Document):
    title = me.StringField(max_length=64, required=True, unique=True)
    start_date = me.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    end_date = me.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow())
    duration = me.IntField() #  sprint duration
    sequence = me.IntField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **values):
        super(Project, self).__init__( *args, **values)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

     def get_current_sprint(self):
         ''' A logic here to calculate the current sprint.'''
```

And anther model sprint:

```
class Sprint(me.Document):
    start_date = me.DateTimeField()
    end_date = me.DateTimeField()
    sequence = me.IntField(required=True, default=0, unique_with='project')
    project = me.ReferenceField('Project')
```

If I have `project` instance then I can get current sprint by calling the method as

```
project.get_current_sprint()
```

But What I am trying to is ; whenever a project object is being queried, rather than calling a method to get the current sprint, it should have an attribute `project.current_sprint` which has the current sprint info.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept of what you're looking for is called [Database References](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) in MongoDB.

In MongoEngine, you would probably create a [ReferenceField](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) in your Project model, which would reference a Sprint document.

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid. Rather than adding another field in the model, I want get it on the fly whenever I am referring a project instance.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to achieve something similar, and while I don't know the entire answer, I'll post what I have identified.  The thing you probably want done should be presumably enabled by a query set (which you would access through `Project.objects`).  Mongoengine creates one, but allows you to replace it, so that when you get (`Project.objects.get(...)`) for instance, it might "prefetches" the sprint relevant to this project.  How to do that is probably through the `mongoengine` [query](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html) syntax, which I'm not yet familiar with.
In the end, it's possible you'll have to combine properties and cache to achieve what you want. the queried project will have a dynamic reference to a sprint (say `project.sprint`) and you could have a property on `Project` to check whether this data exists (and if not, query it).